# MySql workbench: access denied for user root@192.168.2.199 but this doesn't match the host i'm trying to access

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to connect to a MySql 5.1 server on 192.168.2.41 but the error message talks about host 192.168.2.199.  This is not the host i'm trying to login to.  I can login using a lesser account 'XBMC'.

Here's the image of the window, and the text will follow.
[image: MySql workbench access denied but hostname doesn't match]

[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench

[Main Instruction]
Cannot Connect to Database Server

[Content]
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 192.168.2.41:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.2.199' (using password: YES)

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 192.168.2.41
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 192.168.2.41 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 192.168.2.41 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

[Close]

Answer (score 2):

192.168.2.199 is the IP address of your PC you are running MySQL Workbench on. MySQL allows to specify addresses certain users are allowed to connect from. In your case root is not allowed to connect from 192.168.2.199.

By default MySQL creates user `root` as `'root'@'localhost'`. To remove the restriction you need to rename the user to `'root'@'%'`